# Nuget - Add Library package reference - No packages found in the current package source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I am not able to see any packages in the Add Library package reference dialog. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

---

It is definitely related to the network I use. I connected from office and saw no packages and now from home I am seeing all the packages without any change. May be firewall restrictions in the office..Not sure though.

Comment: Right click on that package source and paste in in a browser.  Wat do you see?  I get forwarded to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/

Comment: no idea.  Service is up.

Comment: It is definitely related to the network I use. I connected from office and saw no packages and now from home I am seeing all the packages without any change. May be firewall restrictions in the office..Not sure though.

Comment: Can you try out the build on this thread http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/268781 and see if it resolves your issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind a proxy then this might be your problem. Currently NuGet 1.3 only supports Integrated Authentication so if your organization requires a different type of authentication to get to the outside world then you'll have to wait until the coming proxy feature is implemented which should happen soon.
One thing I would also recommend is that you try the current Package Explorer and see if you are able to browse the current NuGet repository.

Answer (score 0):

try adding -IncludePreRelease as all packages marked such are hidden from you